# EncodeError with \xa3 (pound sign)

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to get some data from a web page. This webpage has stated that charset is utf-8. But there is a problem with \xa3 sign. I can't be encoded or decoded into/from 'utf-8'.

```
for key,value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            if key not in self.db_attributes:
                print repr(value)
                attrs_statement+=str(key)+', '
                values_statement+=str(value)+', '
```

ERROR:

```
u'\xa3410'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Velvet_scraper\vehicle.py", line 432, in <module>
    v.prepare_insert_statement('motorhog_temp')
  File "C:\Users\Milano\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\Velvet_scraper\vehicle.py", line 381, in prepare_insert_statement
    values_statement+=str(value)+', '
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is wrong with that please?

EDIT:

Whole method:

```
def prepare_insert_statement(self,table):
        log('prepare_insert_statement, table: {0}'.format(table))

        attrs_statement = "("
        values_statement = "("

        for key,value in self.__dict__.iteritems():
            if key not in self.db_attributes:
                print repr(value)
                attrs_statement+=key+', '
                values_statement+=value+', '

        attrs_statement+=')'
        values_statement+=')'
        statement = """INSERT INTO TABLE {0}{1} VALUES{2}""".format(table,attrs_statement,values_statement)
        return statement
```

Comment: What type of object is `values_statement`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str()` implicitly encodes Unicode objects with the ASCII codec. Explicitly encode your object, or do not use `str()` objects and build up a Unicode string instead:

```
values_statement += value.encode('utf8') + ', '
```

Comment: Thanks, I've removed str() and it seems to help. But now, it raises the same thing (UnicodeEncodeError for \xa3) on the last line """INSERT INTO table...""" I've edited my code so you can see it there.

Comment: @Milan: you should **not** use string interpolation for database insertions. Use SQL parameters and leave encoding Unicode data to the database driver.