# How to strip \xa3 from all the numbers in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of a dataframe which is read in from a csv file using `pd.read_csv`.  When I look at the numbers they all look like:

```
df['Amount'][0]
Out[4]: '\xa3128.23'
```

That is they have `\xa3` preprended to them and are also therefore not interpreted as floats.

How can I strip of the `\xa3` and make them floats?

Comment: Is the data set one that you can share? If its sensitive I understand. But I would like to see whats going in.

Comment: @csevier When I do `[df['Amount'][i] for i in range(len(df['Amount']))]` I just looks like `['\xa3128.23',
 '\xa3179.47',
 '\xa342.0',
 '\xa31238.29',
 '\xa3408.0', ...`  It is a csv export from an online bank.  I think it might be the "pound sign".

Comment: `a3` is the hex value of the pound sign. Maybe you can use `trim()` or something similar (like substring) before conversion to float?

Comment: Oh okay, so it looks like it may be an encoding problem maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746333/encodeerror-with-xa3-pound-sign?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Pandas read_readcsv supports encoding encoding : str, default None

Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. ‘utf-8’).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['Amount'].str.replace('\xa3', '').astype(float)
```

Or [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) by `£`:

```
df['Amount'].str.lstrip('£').astype(float)
```

As @csevier pointed there seems encoding problem, solution is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("your_data_set_path", encoding='utf-8')
```

And then:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.lstrip('£').astype(float)
```

Comment: This would work but it would take extra algorithms, i think it may be better to handle encoding problem on import of the data set with pandas. 

read_csv("your_data_set_path", encoding='utf-8')

Comment: @csevier - Thank you, I agree with you, there seems problem with encoding.

Comment: Thank you. Your first suggestion using `replace` works. Sadly the encoding idea hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 1):

As @jezrael and I were discussing on his answer, It may be better to handle the encoding on import with pandas instead of loop stripping the result. This is because the extra loops wont scale well with larger data sets and may lead to some slow runtimes.

```
 pd.read_csv("your_data_set_path", encoding='utf-8') #use appropriate encoding.
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: can you give me a single line out of the csv?

Comment: I am not really sure how to provide it. Using cat -A one line is ""14 Dec 2017","DIRECT DEBIT TRANSACTION","M-#1238.29","CR"^M$"  . If I just use `less` and then copy and paste the same line is ""14 Dec 2017","DIRECT DEBIT TRANSACTION","<A3>1238.29","CR""

Comment: so it may be that utf-8 is not the right encoding. I was trying to suggest that in my code comment.